# How to achieve 'size', 'max' and 'min' validations in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, validation, jpa, orm

I have to add some field validations in entity classes. But I did not found any such validations in javax.persistence package interfaces.

These are available in javax.validation package interfaces. So those will work for entity fields if not how to achieve field validations in JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already look for [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/)?

Example would be.

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20)
    private String author;
    ...
}
```

See : [Bean Validation](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2010/03/03/bean-validation-with-jpa-1-0/)  for jpa integration.